# ASP.NET Update panel problem

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an update panel in my page which runs a function and sends an e-mail fine but when I added in the code below it doesn't seem to add it correctly to the page

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myscript", "/scripts/myscript.js")
```

All the other stuff in my `Sub` runs fine but it just seems to not run that bit?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here's my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>

    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"
        Text="Name" />

    <asp:LinkButton ID="button1" OnClick="submitbutton1" runat="server"
        Text="SUBMIT" />

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the `Sub`

```
Sub submitbutton1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Response.write("Test")      

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myscript", "/scripts/myscript.js")

End Sub
```

Comment: so when the UpdatePanel posts back, you want to add a new script tag into your page?

Comment: @Graham Clark yes I'd like to add a new script file on postback

Comment: @Akram Shahda - i've added my code to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude. There is a catch, though. For each script that you want to include asynchronously, you must end it with

```
if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```