# Another Update Panel problem ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, response.addheader

This is a branch off of my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6137390/372364)

I am now able to add my javascript in asynchronously but it does not redirect my page properly.

Currently I use this to redirect my page

```
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "1;URL=mypage.aspx")
```

The reason I use the `Response.AddHeader` is so that I can delay the redirect

Is there something different I need to do with this to make it add the header asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried redirecting with javascript?

```
setTimeout("window.location='mypage.aspx';", 1000);
```

Comment: As a last resort i'd use javascript but was wondering if there was a .Net way of doing it

Comment: If you are doing in the .Net why then why not just use `Response.Redirect`? To get a delay before the redirect put the thread to sleep `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

Comment: If I use `Thread.Sleep` it stops my jQuery from running the exit functions

Comment: ahh sorry didnt realise u had some jquery running. might as well go with the javascript method then if you are already running javascript!